# Invert nested collections in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Having a list of type A, each containing a list of type B, what's the best way to get a list of all type B, each containing a list of type A to which they belong?

Having a list like the following:

```
var parents = new List<Parent> {
    {
        new Parent {
            ID = 1,
            Childs = new List<Child> {
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }                    
    },
    {
        new Parent {
            ID = 2,
            Childs = new List<Child> {
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 4
                    }
                },
                {
                    new Child {
                        ID = 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }                    
    }
};
```

I would like to query this to receive the following result:

```
[
  {
    Child = 1,
    InParent = [1]
  },
  {
    Child = 2,
    InParent = [1]
  },
  {
    Child = 3,
    InParent = [1, 2]
  },
  {
    Child = 4,
    InParent = [2]
  },
  {
    Child = 5,
    InParent = [2]
  },
]
```

**EDIT:** I tried an approach to flatten the childs first using `SelectMany` & `Distinct`, but not sure how to link this to the parent again:

```
var foo =
    from childId in parents.SelectMany(x => x.Childs).Select(x => x.ID).Distinct()
    select
        new
        {
            childId = childId,
            inParent = // Missing Part
        };
```

Comment: have you tried anything before asking a question? What is your problem?

Comment: Sure, I tried to flatten the childs with SelectMany / Distinct, which returns the distinct list of all involved childs, but without connection to the parent where they belonged to. Of course I could iterate with loops through it, my question is how to achieve this in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `SelectMany` first to flatten them, then use `GroupBy` to group by child-id and `String.Join` to concat each parent-id:

```
var childParents = parents
    .SelectMany(p => p.Childs.Select(c => new {Parent = p, Child = c}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Child.ID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Child = g.Key,
        InParent = String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.Parent.ID))
    });
```

Result:

[image]

If you actually don't want that `InParent` property is a string but a `List<int>`(or array) use this:

```
.....
InParent = g.Select(x => x.Parent.ID).ToList()  // or ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your large problem into two simpler problems:

1. Create an anonymous object for each parent/child pair, containing a reference to the parent as well as to the child. You can use a simple LINQ query with two `from` clauses for that.
2. Group those objects into the representation you need. The `group by` clause is your friend here.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should try changing your data model if you are looking for storing tree like structure, in that scenario you should always use single Linked List with custom object & nested reference to corresponding parent / child in the similar way you store in database.

It is an ideal way to handle data structures of such kind as such otherwise you will end up in many nested queries.